# Which constructor will called first in the below example

Tags: c#, asp.net

Which constructor will called first in the below example? When i put break point and execute it first pointed to child constructor but executed the parent class constructor, why this?

could any one please clarify me?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Child child = new Child();
            child.print();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent Constructor.");
    }

    public void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a Parent Class.");
    }
}

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        public Child()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Child Constructor.");
        }
        public new void print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm a Child Class.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors, when generated from C#, are invoked base-class first, so:

- object()
- then Parent()
- then Child()

Essentially the chained `base:.ctor({args})` is prepended to the local `.ctor`

For this reason you should avoid calling virtual methods during construction, as if Child overrides it, it could fail as Child hasn't initialized the fields defined there yet (they will be zeros).

In C++/CLI you get to choose what order to do things.

Comment: if this is the case: when i debug, why the compiler points to the child class constructor first and then executes the parent class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Parent is constructed first because it's at the heart of Child.
Child can't be constructed if it's core (Parent) isn't.

Note that the initialization of the class is not limited to executing its constructor. It also initializes its fields.

In the example below, you really want Child's constructor to show that x=3. If not, it would mean that your derived class can't be based on its ancestor behaviour.

```
  public class Parent 
  {
    public int x;
    public Parent() 
    {
      x = 3;
    }
  }

  public class Child : Parent 
  { 
    public Child() 
    { 
      Console.WriteLine("Child Constructor. x="+x.ToString()); 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Strictly speaking it *has already* been constructed; the constructor just initializes things. And it is IIRC an *implementation* detail that C# always does base-first. At the IL level either is valid, IIRC.

Comment: Marc, what do you think about the example I added? Do you agree? TIA.